# php CURL - multiple independent sessions - need help!

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl

Here is my dilemma...
I basically have a script which by means of CURL posts to a 3rd party website to perform a login and then makes another post to update a users details based on that login session. Now as my site is getting busy I have multiple users doing the same thing and it seems that on occasion curl is getting confused and updating one users details with a different users information. This is causing real problems. 
It seems to be that the cookie which is being used by a user after one login is being shared by other users and they end up logging in with the same cookie - confusing the 3rd party system. My code is posted below and I need to use the cookiefile and cookiejar to maintain the php session to allow me to do what I need to do. But it seems like the same cookie is being reused by all users....
Does that make sense? Is there anything I can do to change this? Please advise....
Thanks so much!

Below is the code i use to both login and post the user update

```
function hitForm($postURL, $postFields, $referer="", $showerr = FALSE, $ispost = TRUE) {
    global $islocal, $path_escape;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postURL);
    if ($ispost)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    else
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($error = curl_error($ch)) {
        if ($showerr)
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $error;
        return -1;
        exit;
    }
    $CU_header = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $CU_header["err"] = curl_errno($ch);
    $CU_header["errmsg"] = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $returnout = $ret;

    //for debugging purposes for now we are logging all form posts
    SaveLog("hitform", "F[".$this->curruserid." - ".$this->currfunc." - ".date("d-m-y h:i:s")."]".$postFields);

    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same cookies.txt file for each session, so that's where the shared cookie problem is coming from. You'd need to specify a seperate file for each parallel session you want to run.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a shared cookie jar for all users. Each user needs a separate cookie jar.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use different cookie files for each user.

I assume your postFields includes some unique identifier for each user (like a user id, or a username), so try something like:

```
$cookie_file = 'cookies_' . $postFields['user_id'] . '.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem, your script is getting wrong user information. How do you store user info anyway?

I'd say that's the source of the problem - you don't assign a unique identifier to user info, and that's where it gets nasty ;)

So, first of all, I'd associate session id with user information (or let's say, store user information in session, which is unique for everyone), and load it from there. And I guess it should do the trick ;)